# Good practice to write a daemon for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon

I would like to run a websocket listener on the server to listen for message and update data or invoke worker accordingly. I would like to write it as a Rails module so it can update ActiveRecord and enqueue Sidekiq task seamlessly. What is the good practice in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through many possible practices and found out that `rails runner` is the best for me.

You can also look for rake tasks.

And absolutely sure you can give a try to [Faye-rails](https://github.com/jamesotron/faye-rails) which will handle all the work without running separate workers explicitly.

Comment: How would you daemonize the rails runner? With upstart?

Comment: Faye-rails sounds nice, but I actually prefer running a separated push server (socket.io) to easily spot and manage memory leak and handle a lot of connections.

Comment: Yep, you can daemonize with upstart or foreman

Comment: Mark yours as accepted before these folk close the questions :D Thanks for the help.